# wget in Colab not downloading complete file

Tags: google-drive-api, google-colaboratory

I have a directory (temp0) on Google Drive which holds 100,000 small files. I cannot open it in Google colab, presumeably because there are too many files.
So I have created a temp0.tar.gz file using python tarfile which is 489KB and I want to download that from my Google Drive and untar it in the Colab environment.
I have used :

```
!wget -O temp0.tar.gz https://drive.google.com/open?id=1lmGFLXtkvhucF033MmBW9yNiAaEgk4_d&authuser=alantjohnstone%40gmail.com&usp=drive_fs
```

It seems to work reporting:

```
Resolving drive.google.com (drive.google.com)... 74.125.31.113, 74.125.31.102, 74.125.31.138, ...
Connecting to drive.google.com (drive.google.com)|74.125.31.113|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 302 Found
Location: https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=wise&passive=1209600&continue=https://drive.google.com/open?id%3D1lmGFLXtkvhucF033MmBW9yNiAaEgk4_d&followup=https://drive.google.com/open?id%3D1lmGFLXtkvhucF033MmBW9yNiAaEgk4_d [following]
--2021-12-06 16:14:13--  https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?service=wise&passive=1209600&continue=https://drive.google.com/open?id%3D1lmGFLXtkvhucF033MmBW9yNiAaEgk4_d&followup=https://drive.google.com/open?id%3D1lmGFLXtkvhucF033MmBW9yNiAaEgk4_d
Resolving accounts.google.com (accounts.google.com)... 64.233.170.84, 2607:f8b0:400c:c07::54
Connecting to accounts.google.com (accounts.google.com)|64.233.170.84|:443... connected.
HTTP request sent, awaiting response... 200 OK
Length: unspecified [text/html]
Saving to: ‘temp0.tar.gz’
temp0.tar.gz            [ <=>                ]  89.18K  --.-KB/s    in 0.001s  
2021-12-06 16:14:13 (60.9 MB/s) - ‘temp0.tar.gz’ saved [91323]
```

However it has only downloaded 90K of the 489K
I have not been able to open the result to see what it actually is.
Could somebody tell me what I am doing wrong?

Comment: What does this have to do with Python? Aside from that, look at the output from `wget` - it is downloading data of type `text/html`. Try renaming your downloaded `tar.gz` file as `something.html` and looking at it in a browser.

Answer (score 2):

I discovered how to move a large file FROM Google Drive TO the colab environment.

1 Get the file ID by right clicking the file and selecting the Get Link.
Copy the link and change the permission to Anybody with Link

2 In Colab paste the link into a cell and prefix with !gdown --id

3 NOTE You have to remove all the Garbage BEFORE AND AFTER the ID
eg https://drive.google.com/file/d/1m3NvCCyuRptopEPBXSPHaNCkfVx4E6ZR/view?usp=sharing
The ID is 1m3NvCCyuRptopEPBXSPHaNCkfVx4E6ZR

Answer (score 0):

i don't think you're able to download stuff directly from google drive, also you need to put the urls in a quote. one solution would be to mount your google drive with the button on the left.